# What distribution is result of division of two poisson distributed metrics?

Tags: normal-distribution, poisson-distribution, p-value, significant-figures

I've got two variables A and B with ≤ following a Poi(), resp. Poi() distribution.

Given values a1 and b1 we can figure out if these particular values are significantly decreased by calculating the probability of getting a1 and b2 or lower number:

[image]

where n=a and n=b,
 =  and  = b
accordingly for each variable.

If the probability of getting a1(or b1) or lower value <5% threshold we can say that this particular value significantly decreased.

My question is how can we figure out the answer to the same question for variable C := A/B (so it is between 0 and 1). If we have got the value of c1 = a1/b2 then how do we know if c1 significantly decreased?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that, instead of $C:=A/B$, you consider random variable:

$$C:=B-A$$

In particular $C$ should be (or tested to be) Poisson-distributed with a parameter that you will call $\lambda c$. You should get $c:=b-a$ due to a version of the [additive property of Poisson random variables](http://thomaswhitham.pbworks.com/f/7.Additive+properties+of+two+independent+Poisson+random+Variables.pdf). In this case, "significantly less" could be translated into "$C$ takes comparatively high values".

**Remarks :**

1) if sometimes $A > B$, you have no longer a Poisson distribution ; see in this case ([Distribution of difference between independent Poisson random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2934636)).

2) If you aren't convinced that it is better to study the difference, and keep trying to study the quotient $C:=A/B$, here is [a reference](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/376963) that can be of interest.

---

Edit : following our exchanges, if $C$ is defined by $C=B-A$, i.e. $B=A+C$, therefore $A/B=A/(A+C)=1/(1+C/A)$, I have done a simulation of Random Variable $R=A/B=1/(1+C/A)$ (see below)

[image]

Taking $A$ and $C$ both Poisson with resp. parameters $\lambda=20$ and $\lambda=25$, we obtain a rather gaussian distribution. Here is the Matlab program that has generated this histogram:

> ```
> function ratpoi;
> for q=1:100000
>    A=poi(20);C=poi(25);
>    T(q)=1/(1+C/A); 
> end;
> hist(T,30);
>
> function P=poi(L); % gen. Poisson Rand. Var. with par. L
> EL=exp(-L);k=0;p=1;
> while p>EL
>     p=p*rand;k=k+1;
> end
> P=k-1;
> ```

Comment: hi @Jean Marie and thanks for your answers and corrections! I corrected my answer based on that so (hopefully) its easier to see what im after. Im trying to figure out if we have variable that is C := A/B then how can we say that particular value c1 = a1/b1 significantly decreased? Im suspecting C is no plonger Poisson distributed?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "decreased" ... Do you mean "small" or "small with respect to..." ?

Comment: Let's say my λa=50, and value of a1 = 33, im trying to figure out what are the probability of getting a1 or lower given λa. I do this using the formula in the question. If the probability is 5% or lower i assume it is a significant decrease.  Here are more details on that: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341960/poisson-distribution-for-large-numbers/3341970?noredirect=1#comment6878863_3341970

Comment: I understand a little better. You should have given this reference at first in your question. Besides, saying that you have two Poisson random variables such that $A \leq B$ without explaining more is **not correct** (and will introduce flaws in any further reasoning) unless you explain why and how $A$ is linked with $B$. This is why it is so natural to introduce $A$ and $C$ (both Poisson with different parameters) and **then** define $B=A+C$, wich guarantees that $A \leq B$.

Comment: (ctd) in this way, you will have to study $A/B=1/(1+C/A)$ where $A$ and $C$ are both Poisson distributed.

Comment: i see thanks! Also, i probably should've mentioned that A and B are a different kind of variables, ie A is orders and B is clicks - doest it still make sense defining B = A+C? And if so given /=1/(1+/) how can i say that a1/b1 significantly decreased? It is not poisson distributed anymore or is it?

Comment: See my edit answering your question.